# Upload many ftp files at once?

Tags: file, ftp

I have about 2,000 small files. I want to upload them to a server using FileZilla and it keeps kicking me out and telling me this:

```
Status: Delaying connection for 1 second due to previously failed connection attempt...
Status: Resolving address of ....www.blabla.com
Status: Connecting to 10.10.10
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] ----------
Response:   220-You are user number 12 of 500 allowed.
Response:   220-Local time is now 14:46. Server port: 21.
Response:   220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
Response:   220 You will be disconnected after 3 minutes of inactivity.
Command:    USER user2
Response:   331 User user2 OK. Password required
Command:    PASS ********
Response:   421 I can't accept more than 5 connections as the same user
```

Is there a better way to upload many files?

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 > Go to Site Manager > transfer settings > Check the limit number of simultaneous connections and give it 1 connection > reconnect
Option 2 > Change FTP password to break current connections > an then reconnect

both options will not working if your hosting server giving a limit for ftp user connections then you must contact your hosting provider or upgrade your account

Answer (score 0):

The log just says that multiple connections are not allowed in your FTP. Make sure that there are not more than five persons connected at the same time.